# How to create primary index in my Couchbase server use query?

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I have written the following code to create primary index in Couchbase server with my Symfony project.

```
    // Establish connection
    $cluster = new \CouchbaseCluster('http://ec2-ip_number.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8091'); // http://127.0.0.1:8091
    $bucket = $cluster->openBucket("default");
    $bucket->enableN1ql(array('http://ec2-ip_number.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8091'));

    // Execute query
    $query = 'CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `default-primary-index` ON `default` USING GSI';
    $queryNql = \CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString($query);
    $bucket->query($queryNql);
```

My couchbase cluster is created in amazon aws. 
After run the above code, it shows me the error:

> "LCB_NETWORK_ERROR: Generic network failure. Enable detailed error codes (via LCB_CNTL_DETAILED_ERRCODES, or via `detailed_errcodes` in the connection string) and/or enable logging to get more information
>   500 Internal Server Error - CouchbaseException"

I have tried it many times to solve this issue, but couldn't able to get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the CREATE INDEX command from the web-console (query-tab). Make sure there are no connectivity/network issues between client & server, or between various Couchbase services.

Did you retry after enabling logging?? What error do you see in logs?
Provide more details on couchbase version and AWS/cluster setup?

-Prasad

Comment: My running version is 4.0.0-4051 Community Edition (build-4051). There is no query tab in my web console. 

Error details is now: 
"LCB_NETWORK_ERROR: Generic network failure. Enable detailed error codes (via LCB_CNTL_DETAILED_ERRCODES, or via `detailed_errcodes` in the connection string) and/or enable logging to get more information"

How do I can enabling logging?

Comment: looks like some conn issue. Did you try using cbq shell to connect and run some basic queries. Otherwise, check your network connectivity.

Comment: Sure. I will try.